# how to convert json parent objects and childs into html dom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, get

I get an API where i have an objects and items in objects.
I have first level, second level and third level arrays, i only need firts and second levels.
How i can display an items for first level objects in html dom?

i only need items with ids = 457 > 458 - 459 - 460 - 461  - 464 - 581, 472 > ....;
its a tree categories
and how i can match code of first level object with child(second level objects)

here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [
    {
        "id": 457,
        "name": "name457",
        "code": "url457",
        "icon": "",
        "productsCount": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 458,
                "name": "name458",
                "code": "url458",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 741,
                        "name": "name741",
                        "code": "url741",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 743,
                        "name": "name743",
                        "code": "url743",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": 459,
                "name": "name459",
                "code": "url459",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": 460,
                "name": "name460",
                "code": "url460",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": 461,
                "name": "name461",
                "code": "url461",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 599,
                        "name": "name599",
                        "code": "url599",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 742,
                        "name": "name742",
                        "code": "url742",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 744,
                        "name": "name744",
                        "code": "url744",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 882,
                        "name": "name882",
                        "code": "url882",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": 464,
                "name": "name464",
                "code": "url464",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 883,
                        "name": "name883",
                        "code": "url883",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 884,
                        "name": "name884",
                        "code": "url884",
                        "icon": null,
                        "productsCount": 1,
                        "image": null
                    }
                ],
                "image": null
            },
            {
                "id": 581,
                "name": "name581",
                "code": "url581",
                "icon": null,
                "productsCount": 1,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "image": null
    },
    {
        "id": 472,
        "name": "name472",
        "code": "url472",
        "icon": "milk",
        "productsCount": 1,
        "items": []
    }
]
      var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
      var HTML = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
          item = data[i];
          items = keys[j];
          HTML +=
            '<div class="css-firstLVL-cat"><a class="" target="_blank" href="https://firstLVL-cat/' +
            item.code + '">' + item.name +
            '</a ><div class="css-secondLVL-cat"><a class="" target="_blank" href="https://firstLVL-cat/secondLVL-cat' +
          item.items.code + '">' + item.items.name + '</a ></div></div > ';

        }
      }
      $('#gable').append(HTML);
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="css-1">
    <div class="css-2">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="css-3">
            <div id="gable" class="css-items">

            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the ajax works, remove it from the [mcve] and have a complete example of only the object and the loop

Comment: @mplungjan change it to json data